# Is it possible to read nfc tag UID with PhoneGap? How?

Tags: cordova, nfc, phonegap-plugins

I would like to read an `NFC` tag's `UID`, tags don't have any `ndef` message or anything (empty), just `UID`. It's easy to do on Android, but Phonegap development is way faster so I would like to know if it's possible to get it working on Phonegap, probably using the [phonegap-nfc](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [phonagap-nfc plugin](http://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) will allow you to read the `tag's UID`.

`nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener()` is good if you need the tag id.  As of `phonegap-nfc-0.4.0` the tag id is also included with the `NDEF` listeners when it is available.

You can convert the id to a hex string for display with `nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id)`

```
function ready() {

    function onNfc(nfcEvent) {

        var tag = nfcEvent.tag;
        var tagId = nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);
        alert(tagId);

    }

    function win() {
        console.log("Listening for NFC Tags");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("Error adding NFC listener");
    }


    nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(onNfc, win, fail);
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', ready, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question: yes, use the NFC plugin. Add a callback for any tag with `nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener()`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the phonegap nfc plugin, the app works fine with no errors on the log, I get undefined whenever I read tags UID.